# Is it necessary to allocate an allocatable array?

Tags: fortran, allocation

I have a simple question regarding derived types and allocated arrays.
Suppose we have defined the type

```
type demo_type
        real(kind=8),allocatable :: a(:)
end type demo_type
```

and the function

```
function demo_fill(n) result(b)
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        real(kind=8) :: b(n)
        b = 1.d0
end function demo_fill
```

Is it correct to write in the main program

```
type(demo_type) :: DT
DT%a = demo_fill(3)
```

Or is it necessary to first allocate DT%a to prevent accidentally overwriting other variables in memory?

```
type(demo_type) :: DT
allocate(DT%a(3))
DT%a = demo_fill(3)
```

They both compile, but I am wondering which is the correct way. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Fortran 2003 any allocatable array can be allocated automatically on assignment.

In your case

```
DT%a = demo_fill(3)
```

causes `DT%a` to be automatically allocated to the shape of the right hand side, which is the result of the function, if it has not been allocated to this shape previously.

This behavior is standard, but some compilers do not enable it by default, notably the Intel Fortran. You must use special compiler flags to enable it (`-standard-semantics`, `-assume realloc_lhs`)

As a side note, `kind=8` does not mean 8-byte reals on all compilers, and this usage is frowned upon (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/856243/721644).